# Asset routing issue in combination with slug and date

Tags: assets, image, routing

Normally I add images to a post through a field for it, but now I thought I'd just use the uploader in the text/newspost field. However, this gives me the following problem.

When on index.htm for the blog channel the image is shown.

```
http://inquisimunda.evinwijninga.com/uploads/Facebook-Banner.gif
```

When I go to the the posts page itself however, the post isn't shown as it can't be found. It also isn't shown in the text editor when I edit the post. (Broken image link).

```
http://inquisimunda.evinwijninga.com/article/2015/uploads/Facebook-Banner.gif
```

I have never tried to fix routing issues before as I had never had any issues like this before.

Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? "now I thought I'd just use the uploader in the text/newspost field" - You're referring to uploading directly from an Assets field in an entry?  And is the issue that it works fine on your front-end template, but not in the CP? And it sounds like maybe you're doing it from a Rich Text field in the CP?

Comment: The uploading I did from the text editor itself.

However, I found the fault already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I made was entering "uploads/" in the url in file management. This should be "/uploads".[image]